# Magento 2: how to change Category page design

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute, category-view

I have a theme installed on my Magento V2.2.3 site and now i would like to change the category page design with requirements

- new custom fields for category
- option on each category if this category will be visible with new design or not
- if yes, then i need category custom fields which will have slider image and text box which i need to put above product list.

Can someone tell how i can achieve this

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding and/or overriding containers and blocks from the `catalog_category_view.xml` file which is located at:

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml
```

To add custom attributes, you might want to look to put a block before `category.products` in a custom `phtml` file.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Rewrite\Category\View" name="custom.attributes" template="MyVendor_MyModule::category/products.phtml" before="category.products">
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I'm writing a module for this, can you please tell me which files i need to override category page